# Strongest LPG hose on earth

Tags: gas

My LPG (Liquified Petroleum Gas) hose is made of rubber and already 10 years old. I want to replace it to avoid any leak and explosion. I only need about a 37 inches (1 meter) of LPG hose. What is the strongest one around perhaps made of steel or better and bendable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: depends on what is available in your country.

Comment: I can buy it at amazon so location not the limit

Comment: Will that mean it meets the safety standards in your country? Covered by insurance?

Comment: We only use rubber here. And insurance doesnt look at it. I need steel reinforced hose to be sure any rat cant just bite the rubber..

Comment: Black iron pipe, and forget hose. Pick a fixed spot for the tank and stove burner.

Comment: But the connector of the stove is for hose. How do you connect the black iron pipe to the hose?

Answer (score 2):

Not the best, but I'd say, `Pigeon Steel Wire Reinforced LPG Hose`, available on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00NZ3MX6I/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sl1&tag=bestgasstove0b-21&linkId=d81b93fc62ff429d0c7bf7bea4436b94&language=en_IN).
Steel reinforced hose is meant for rodent protection and this one serves the purpose, it has 5 years of warranty.